# Upgraded to Laravel 5.4 - Some routes now fail?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I had a completely working project on `Laravel 5.3`, yesterday I upgraded to `Laravel 5.4` locally to check all was working and was very happy so put a plan in place to move it live.

Where I have now deployed the site on my `forge.laravel.com` managed servers, most of the routes work okay but when trying to log out I get the following error:

[image]

I'm not quite sure what the issue actually is. This site works totally fine locally. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: have you checked `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` in productiom php.ini? it looks like the limits are different between online and local

Comment: I'm just logging out, not uploading anything @Mr.Phoenix

Comment: try debugging the request sent to logout users it should be a simple `Auth::logout` call inside an GET request don't know why exceeds limits

Comment: What's the best way to do that @Mr.Phoenix? `/logout` is inside the Laravel make:auth package

Comment: `post_max_size = 8m` and `upload_max_size = 2m` @Mr.Phoenix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick fix (after emailing Taylor) he suggested that I comment out the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,` middleware inside `app\Html\Kernal.php`

Tried it and it worked perfectly!

Easy fix when you know how! haha

Comment: No idea why anyone downvoted this, this came from the guy that created the framework!

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar issue, I have tried to increase my limits too. You can't do them on ini file in laravel 5.4 but you can add your customizations on public/.htaccess

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399301/7596103

Comment: It's on Laravel Forge so an NGINX environment. I did try to set them in there but commenting out the middleware was the solution from Taylor so I went with it haha