# Laravel : all forms throw PostTooLargeException

Tags: laravel

I have a  dashboard running laravel 5.6

it works fine on local but once running on liver server on a shared hosing
nearly any form with 3 or 4 fields throws **PostTooLargeException**
as the picture below.

the request it not happening yet.

as you can see the post is empty.

i tried to renter same data to test validation , the validation never get to run. like it fails before request and validation.

the error in picture invoked by form of 6 text and one select menu.Nevertheless, it is  same with any other form except forms with one text only

**Edit**

i have run ini_get again , the tinker return "64M" but the web page return only 128 without metrics or quotes

the $request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') is 153 only

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `post_max_size` in your php.ini?

Comment: i run it on tinker it was "64M"

Comment: The solving way may be in here for your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001414/posttoolargeexception-in-validatepostsize-php-line-22-laravel

Comment: @FGDeveloper unfortunately, there is no uploads , and i have a error handling and validation for each form

Comment: @Jerodev
now i have run ini_get again , the tinker return "64M" but the web page return only 128 without metrics or quotes