# PostTooLargeException in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload

When I try to upload a 8.54 mb images it generate a error

> Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException No message

What I really want to do is validation to be done before uploading and a customized error message to be display mentioning that the l image capacity is too large to upload

this is my controller **ProfileController.php**

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){ 
         $request->validate([ 
            'avatar' => 'required|image|max:2048',                 
      ]);

        $user = Auth::user();
        Storage::delete('/avatars/'.$user->avatar); 
        $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.time().'.'.request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->avatar->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);     
        $user->avatar = $avatarName;    
        $user->save(); 

             return back()->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');     
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the exception, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Small file get uploaded but not large file in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529518/small-file-get-uploaded-but-not-large-file-in-laravel)

Comment: First search result for your error message is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42001414/6089612), and the accepted answer shows both how to fix it and how to do validation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used Laravel in a very long time, but here's what I would do. First of all, I expect the `PostTooLargeException` not to come from the form validator but from Laravel itself. What I would do in this case is increase the [`max_post_size`](https://php.net/post_max_size) setting in `php.ini` (and then perhaps [`upload_max_filesize`](https://php.net/upload_max_filesize)).

This will alow the request to arrive to your controller.

Then you can use the validator to handle the error that the image is larger than the specified 2048. For further details regarding displaying errors, you could take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).