# how to edit php settings in Laravel 5.4 to accept large csv file uploads?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I can change max file upload size in php.ini in my local but unable to do the same in Laravel 5.4.
I want to upload 4mb csv file.

Comment: What do you mean you can't? If it is changed in your ini file, then you should be allright...

Comment: May be you should restart your server to check if your change has affected?

Comment: Restart your web server for the config to be reloaded

Comment: laravel doesnt have any INI file to restrict the upload. Its the apache/php.ini config. You will have to change max file upload size and post max size, then finally restart the server.

Comment: @Serge It will get impacted on the local machine only. I was referring to implement changes on the server.

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar the changes did work after I restart but they were getting applied to local only. Thanks for your answer. Found a better approach which I have mentioned below.

Comment: @CerlinBoss I finally figured out how to do it . Thanks for your answer. Found a better approach which I have mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure both your webserver and PHP to allow larger file uploads. 
For PHP you'll want to configure [upload_max_filesize](https://php.net/upload-max-filesize) and [post_max_size](https://php.net/post-max-size) to the size you. E.g.:

```
upload_max_filesize = 5M
post_max_size = 8M
```

For NGINX you'll want to configure [client_max_body_size](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size), and for Apache you'll want to configure [LimitRequestBody](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody).

There are also several other configuration options in your webserver config which could prevent the upload of larger files. Please see the manual of your webserver for how to configure those values correctly.

Note that after configuring these settings you'll want to restart both PHP and your webserver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Found a better approach which I have mentioned below.

Comment: And  I didn't use NGINX at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people for helping me out. 
I know the php.ini file exists in PHP/Apache. If I edit that to increase the upload size, it works in my local. But my aim was to upload it in my laravel website.

After too many hit and trials, I finally found the solution 
you have to edit  public/.htaccess
Add this

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
> php_value post_max_size 20M
> php_value memory_limit 32M
> ```

This will increase the file upload size in Laravel 5.4

I recently started using laravel and upgraded to 5.4 as soon as it released. So, I had many questions.

Comment: Do you realize that this has nothing to do with laravel at all?

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta got the solution. I have written how I did it. Thanks for your answer. Found a better approach which I have mentioned below.